# PDFBox - how to create table of contents

Tags: java, pdfbox

Is there a way to create a table of contents using `Java PDFBox` library?

The table of contents should be clickable (jump to the right page)

Thanks.

Comment: I am also searching same implementation, an you share your solution

Answer (score 0):

There's no simple method for doing this, but here's an approach.  I haven't figured out how to attach links directly to text, so my approach means you have to draw the annotations as rectangles and the text separately.  It's a bit rough around the edges, but it works.

```
// there are other types of destinations, choose what is appropriate
PDPageXYZDestination dest = new PDPageXYZDestination();
// the indexing is odd here.  if you are doing this on the first page of the pdf
// that page is -1, the next is 0, the next is 1 and so on.  odd.
dest.setPageNumber(3);
dest.setLeft(0);
dest.setTop(0); // link to top of page, this is the XYZ part

PDActionGoTo action = new PDActionGoTo();
action.setDestination(dest);

PDAnnotationLink link = new PDAnnotationLink();
link.setAction(action);
link.setDestination(dest);

PDRectangle rect = new PDRectangle();
// just making these x,y coords up for sample
rect.setLowerLeftX(72);
rect.setLowerLeftY(600);
rect.setUpperRightX(144);
rect.setUpperRightY(620);

PDPage page = // however you are getting your table of contents page, eg new PDPage() or doc.getDocumentCatalog().getAllPages().get(0)

page.getAnnotations().add(link);

PDPageContentStream stream = new PDPageContentStream(doc, page, true, true);
stream.beginText();
stream.setTextTranslation(85, 600); // made these up, have to test to see if padding is correct
stream.drawString("Page 1");
stream.endText();
stream.close();
```

Phew!  That's a lotta code.  That should get you on your way.  You can make the rectangle the same color as your document background if you want it to look like they are just clicking a link, but that requires more experimentation.

Comment: According to the PDF specification, the /Dest entry is not permitted if an /A entry is present, so you should delete the "action" part.

Comment: I believe there's a bug - Instead of dest.setPageNumber(3), use dest.setPage(PDPage). Numbers are for external destinations only.

Answer (score 0):

These methods will add clickable table of contents to your document

```
public void addOutline(@NonNull PDDocument document) {
    PDDocumentOutline outline = new PDDocumentOutline();
    outline.addLast(buildPDOutlineItem(document, "Section 1", 0));
    outline.addLast(buildPDOutlineItem(document, "Section 2", 5));
    outline.addLast(buildPDOutlineItem(document, "Section 3", 8));
    document.getDocumentCatalog().setDocumentOutline(outline);
}

private PDOutlineItem buildPDOutlineItem(
       @NonNull PDDocument document, String title, Integer pageNum) {
    PDOutlineItem item = new PDOutlineItem();
    item.setTitle(title);
    item.setDestination(document.getPages().get(pageNum));
    return item;
}
```