# Java PDFBox Multi-Page Document With Headings and Table of Contents

Tags: java, pdfbox

The PDFBox v2.0 is still growing and doesn't have any nice and easy examples to get started with.

I need to create a multi-page PDF dynamically from an object; with TableOfContents and Headings!

How do I create Numbered Headings? (Increasing the font size is not an option because the TableOfContents has to know their location[page number] in the document)

Example:

```
                       Table of Contents    
Document Title Here
      1- Intro......................................................1
      2- Heading....................................................2
           2.1- SubHeading1 ........................................2
           2.2- SubHeading2 ........................................5

                              Page 1
```

```
                       Document Title Here
     1- Intro
           This is an intro to the document....

     2- Heading
     2.1- Subheading
      Some text here...
     ........


                           Page 2
```

I have two problems:

1. I followed this example here: [PDFBox - how to create table of contents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23553094/pdfbox-how-to-create-table-of-contents) but it didn't create any TableOfContents. 
   I'm getting this exception:

   ```
   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Destination of a GoTo action must be a page dictionary object
   at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.interactive.action.PDActionGoTo.setDestination(PDActionGoTo.java:90)
   ```

   I removed the PDActionGoTo as the answer comment said; it didn't give any exception but it didn't create any TableOfContents
2. I have no idea how to make headings!

Comment: re 1), I believe there's a bug in the answer you link to. Instead of dest.setPageNumber(3), use dest.setPage(PDPage). Numbers are for external destinations only.

Comment: re 2) there is no such thing as a "heading" in PDF. It is just text that is at some place in the page, so you put it there just like you would put any text. (PDFBox is very low level. Use itext if you prefer a high level solution)

Comment: Please do also have a look at the AddAnnotations.java example in the source code download. It does show how to make a link that jumps to another page. I have updated this example recently.

Comment: @TilmanHausherr then how do I suggest I fix the Heading/TableOfContents issue? I can't like link them manually!

Comment: @TilmanHausherr wheres this AddAnnotations file

Comment: It is in the source download. Or here: https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/pdfbox/trunk/examples/src/main/java/org/apache/pdfbox/examples/pdmodel/AddAnnotations.java  re "fix the Heading/TableOfContents issue" I don't really understand - there is no such thing as a heading. It's just text at some position. You have to calculate the positions and the numbers and the count of "." yourself.

Comment: @TilmanHausherr hmm. I'm thinking I generate a Word Document with some library to write the headings and all and then convert it to PDF

Comment: If you give up, then please delete your question. I've put a comment on the answer you linked to so the next person will hopefully avoid the IllegalArgumentException.